# Restarting One Database Not Entire Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there anyway to restart one database in SQL Server instead of restarting the entire server?  I have a task in perpetual rollback on one of my databases.  I'd like to restart it without turning off / on the other DBs

Comment: What do you mean 'restart' a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to take the DB offline, but because of the perpetual rollback wasn't able to do so.  Had to eventually restart the server

Answer (score 12):

You can try taking it offline, and then online again:

```
use master
go

alter database YourDatabase
set offline
with rollback immediate
go

alter database YourDatabase
set online
go
```

As per BOL:

> **OFFLINE** : The database is closed, shut down cleanly, and marked offline. The database cannot be modified while it is offline.

Comment: @Andomar To be honest, neither am I.  I'd have to run a test to verify.  But that'd be my next step.